# Disable specific scrollbar when mouse is in a section with a different scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a site that has a div with search results in the middle, that normally has a scrollbar, and then the full body has a scrollbar too when the window is resized or the resolution is too small.

(Sorry, I can't provide a link as I'm in very early stages of development).

The search results will scroll OK when you use the mousewheel, but when you reach the bottom of the results and keep scrolling, it will start scrolling the full document.

I want to avoid that by disabling the external scrollbar when the mouse is over the search results div. Is there a way to do that? How do you target a specific scrollbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#search_box").hover( 
    function(){
            $("body").css("overflow-y","hidden");
    },
    function(){
            $("body").css("overflow-y","scroll");
    }
);
```

[`$.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)